# How to get path from URL when running jar - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, classloader, filepath

I want my code to be able to get file paths (as Strings) while running the application directly from jar. Here is my attempt

```
URL url = LispConnector.class.getResource("/Aima/aima/quicklisp/setup.lisp");
String path = url.getFile();
File f = new File(path);
path = f.getAbsolutePath();
path = path.replace("\\", "/");
```

While this works fine when i run the application from netbeans, the absoulte path returned is incorrect when I run the jar file directly. The path returned is

[image]

When I use the code

```
String path = url.toURI();
File = new File(path);
path = path.getAbsolutePath();
```

Again it works fine while running from netbeans, but shows error "URI is not hierarchical" error while running the jar file.

My question is, how to get the absolute path of a file when running the application directly from jar. 
 I dont want to read the contents of the file, I ONLY need the absoulte path as a string!

Comment: Do not try to access resources within a JAR using a file-path. As they are inside a JAR file they are not part of the file-system (hence not accessible using a file-path). Just retrieve the InputStream using `getResourceAsStream(..)`and then read the data from the InputStream.

Comment: I dont want to read the data, i just need the path as a string!

Comment: If you don't want t read the data what do you want to do with it? check for existence?

Comment: No. It is a lisp file, and I want to load it from lisp command (load filepath) by executing lisp function from java

Comment: also, in my application, i want to display the path of the file on UI

Answer (score 0):

Since my project was dependent on these files, i decided to copy the folder to dist/ folder by adding these lines in build.xml

```
<target name="-post-compile">
<copy todir="${dist.dir}/aima">
<fileset dir="aima/"/>
</copy>
</target>
```

Now I do not need to use GetResource() or GetResourceAsStream().